# How to handle user creation with Firebase social auth and a Rails backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am building a react native application with a rails backend but I decided to go for Firebase for authentication only since it's quite a bit cheaper than Auth0 or Okta.

The setup went fine but I am having trouble figuring out where to call my own backend to create/update a user in the sign in process.

This is my current sign in function that is triggered when pressing the 'Sign in with Facebook' button:

```js
  async function handleAuthentication() {
    const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']);

    if (result.isCancelled) {
      return;
    }

    const data = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

    if (!data) {
      return Alert.alert('Error', 'Something went wrong while authenticating with Facebook.');
    }

    const facebookCredential = auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken);

    // This token doesnt seem to work
    await upsertUser(facebookCredential.token);

    await auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential);
  }
```

What I get back from the `auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken)` is an object with a token but that doesn't seem to be useful.

When I call `auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential);` I do get back the user data that I need to create a user BUT that already triggers the authentication system and sets the user as signed while he/she isn't created in the backend yet.

So ideally, I would like to create the user before calling signInWithCredential.

Although I'm not sure how to do this or with what token?

I use a Rails backend where I can also decode the token if necessary.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could use a firebase function callback to create a user-account in your rails-app in the background. I don't think there is a safe way to do that from the client other than providing a custom oauth login to your rails app.

Comment: That sounds like a possible solution! I should check out the documentation for that since I didn't even thing that was possible. Though I am not sure how to do this securely.